# How to add new column to table using many side of one-to-many relationship

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, relationship

Is the following achievable using Power BI? I have two tables that have a One-to-many relationship. I am trying to add a new column to Table A (one) which will contain the most recent Event Name from Table B (many).

[image: Relationship]

[image: Table A (one)]

[image: Table B (many)]

Desired output - new column on Table A which contains the latest most recent Value from the Many side.

[image: Desired output - new column added to Table A]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a CalculateColumn (in table A):

[image]

```
LatestEvent = var _id = [ID]
var _lastDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Table B'[Date]),'Table B'[ID] = _id)
return
calculate( MAX('Table B'[Name]),'Table B'[Date] = _lastDate && _id = 'Table B'[ID])
```

If you need a measure:

```
MeasureLatestEvent = var _id = SELECTEDVALUE('Table A'[ID])
var _lastDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Table B'[Date]),'Table B'[ID] = _id)
return
calculate( MAX('Table B'[Name]),'Table B'[Date] = _lastDate && _id = 'Table B'[ID])
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfetly!